# How to use test_move.py script from ur_modern_driver

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-industrial, rosrun, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, UR Software 3.3.0.145, and am running Indigo. I am able to get `roslaunch` to work, however when I try to run `rosrun ur_modern_driver test_move.py`. I get the error

```
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: ur_driver
```

I have run the `rosrun` command in a new terminal after running `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Any thoughts or insights are greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Pawel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243801/how-to-use-test_move.py-script-from-ur_modern_driver/) by [Pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27968/pawel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `test_move.py` script from `ur_modern_driver` includes a (as far as I can tell) erronous `roslib.load_manifest(..)` line ([here](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/blob/5b22e46450f1705bb94d397e0dadc01e9dafc094/test_move.py#L3)), that references the `ur_driver` package.

Quick work-around: make sure to have the `ur_driver` package available on your PC: either install `ros-$distro-ur-driver`, or clone the `universal_robot` git repository into your catkin workspace (don't forget to rebuild the workspace).

Now `rosrun ur_modern_driver test_move.py` should work.

You could also just remove the `roslib.load_manifest(..)` line: it is no longer needed.

PS: it would be nice if you could report this to the `ur_modern_driver` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2016-09-15**:
Even if `test_move.py` in `ur_modern_driver` is fixed, having the ROS-I `universal_robot` packages installed seems like a good idea in order to do almost anything useful (e.g. to have the URDF in `ur_description`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-15**:
Yes, good point. Although that depends on what you actually want to do, of course.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2016-09-16**:
Indeed, that's where the *almost* comes from ;)

**Comment by [BigHopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/33916/bighopes/) on 2020-02-04**:
I had the same error: "rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: ur_driver"
and I solved it by: sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ur-driver

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-11-02**:
please anyone help me i am always getting "Waiting for server..." i want to move the ur in gazebo by their joint state cordinates